# How do I make .getline get answers for every time through

Tags: c++, getline

I am a junior programmer, probably bad code which you computer experts can figure out. I have made this memorizing a paragraph program for my own use, can you figure out a way so that the getline happens every time throough? Here's my code...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

void main(){
    string sentence;
    string attempt;
    char key;
    int counter = 0;

    cout << "Insert your sentence / paragraph (will be case sensitive) (don't press     enter until you're done)." << endl << endl;
    getline (cin, sentence);
    cout << endl;
    while (true){
        system ("cls");
        Sleep (5);
        cout << "Now enter the sentence / paragraph" << endl;
            getline (cin, attempt);
        if (sentence == attempt){
            cout << "Good job, do you want to go again? N for no, anything else for     yes" << endl;
            cin >> key;
            if (key == 'n' || key == 'N'){
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            cout << "You messed up, try again." << endl;
            system("pause");
            continue;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ getline() isn't waiting for input from console when called multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786994/c-getline-isnt-waiting-for-input-from-console-when-called-multiple-times)

Answer (score 0):

Without going all the way through your code. It is probable that bytes are being left in the input buffer following a `getline()` call. I'll explain with ASCII art.

Say your buffer looks like this, where every empty box can hold a byte.

`|_|_|_|_|_|...|_|`

When you enter a phrase (like "FOO"), and press Enter, the buffer looks like this:

`|F|O|O|\n|_||_|...|_|`

The `'\n'` character (the newline character) is added by the Enter key.

When `getline()` reads through the buffer, it reads until it hits the newline character, but it doesn't remove it. So, the call looks like:

```
getline(cin, str) // = "FOO"
|\n|_|_|...|_| // buffer after call
```

The next call to `getline()` will read in the newline (and remove it from the buffer).

```
getline(cin, str) // = "\n"
|_|_|_|_|_|...|_| // buffer after call
```

This behaviour has led to the common practise of "clearing the buffer" after reading from the input buffer. This can be achieved by doing

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

after each buffer read. It also helps to define that as a macro or inline function, to quickly call it any time.