# really easy c++: Does the operator >> in fstream remove newline characters after reading something?

Tags: c++, fstream

```
// file.in
12
13

// main.cpp
fstream f("file.in", ios::in);
int n;
char c;
f >> n;
f.get(&c);
```

After extracting the number 12, what is the next character? Is it newline or '1'? If I call getline instread of get, do I get an empty line or '13'?

Comment: ideone doesn't allow file inputs

Comment: It should be the same as standard input with the pre-given input. I guess it does kill the point if the thing in question is specifically `fstream` though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It leaves the delimiter in the input buffer, so the next character you read will be a new-line. Note, however, that most extractors will skip white space (which includes `new-line`) *before* anything they extract, so unless you do call something like `getline` this won't usually be visible.

Edit: to test on something like ideone, consider using a `stringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(){ 
    std::istringstream f("12\n13");
    int n;
    char c;
    f >> n;
    f.get(c); // get takes a reference, not a pointer. Don't take the address.

    std::cout << "'" << c << "'";
    return 0;
}
```

I wouldn't expect to see a difference between a `stringstream` and an `fstream` in something like this.

Comment: Be careful when [mixing getline with operator<<](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7787253/14065)