# Why does getline return empty lines if none exist

Tags: c++, string, io

I have a file containing the following lines:

```
5556
0   bla.dxf
1   blub.dxf
2   buzz.dxf
```

The numbers and text are seperated by a singular tab each, there is no whitespace character after 5556. The following code is used for parsing.

```
int main(int, char**){
  std::ifstream file("test.bld");
  std::string buildingName;
  file >> buildingName;
  std::cout << buildingName << std::endl;
  std::string buf;
  while(getline(file, buf)) {
    if(buf.empty()){std::cout << "String was empty"<<std::endl;}
    else std::cout << buf << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When I parse the file I get an empty line although there obviously is none.
The output reads as follows:

```
5556
String was empty
0   bla.dxf
1   blub.dxf
2   buzz.dxf
```

This is only a minimal example. The whole file and the parser is more complex and I would very much like to use direct parsing for the first element and getline for the rest. What am I misunderstanding about line parsing with `getline` and how do I avoid getting empty lines?

Comment: `operator >>` leaves the new line character in the input buffer - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10842558/1374437).

Comment: Just found the following which explains my mistake: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7787253/484230. The quintessence is: don't mix or you're in for trouble

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming because

```
file >> buildingName;
```

doesn't move the cursor to the next line, but leaves it at the end of the current line. So when you call `getline`, you'll read an empty string and then move to the next.

Comment: That explains things. When is a cursor moved to the next line ? When I have pure stream input this is not a problem in >> a >> b >> c skips also line feeds. But with a dynamic combination of getline() .. in>> a ... getline, when is the linefeed read

Comment: @Martin This is just an assumption (which probably is correct). The thing is I don't know for sure since I never combine the two types of reading. I either use `>>` or `getline`.

Comment: The assumption is correct. `>>` reads the string up to but not including any whitespace (the whitespace is skipped on the next call).

Answer (score 5):

`operator>>(istream, string)` reads [up to but not including](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) the first whitespace character after the extracted token.

To skip the rest of the line after extracting a token, you can either use

```
std::cin >> std::ws;
```

(if you know that there is only a newline remaining), or

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

to skip to the end of the line regardless.