# Why is std::getline() skipped?

Tags: c++

I have this C++ simple program;

```
#include <iostream>
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::getline;

#include <string>
using std::string;


struct Repository
{
    string name;
    string path;
    string type;
    string command;
};


int main()
{
    Repository rp;

    cout << "\nEnter repo name: ";
    cin >> rp.name;

    cout << "Enter repo path: ";
    cin >> rp.path;

    cout << "Enter repo type: ";
    cin >> rp.type;

    cout << "Enter repo command: ";
    getline(cin, rp.command);

    cout << "\nRepository information: " << endl;
    cout << rp.name << "\n" << rp.path << "\n" << rp.type << "\n" << rp.command << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When execution reaches getline(cin, rp.command) the program just print "Enter repo command: " and skips the getline(cin, rp.command) line so that the user is not given time to respond. What could be the possible problem?

Comment: And your struct looks like?

Comment: We would need to see the definition of `Repository`.

Comment: Need more detail. Crash how? What's the type of `.command` ?

Comment: @PaulR, added struct definition.

Comment: @user657267, added struct definition.

Comment: This still doesn't make a minimal, complete example. Show a small but complete test case from include to main and everything else needed to compile it.

Comment: The code above shouldn't crash, your problem is probably elsewhere, post a minimal compilable example that shows the crash.

Comment: Does it crashes or `rp.command` stays empty?

Comment: @Amani [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidelines on posting code

Comment: @Amani the code does not crash for me either, just leaves the `rp.command` empty.

Comment: Your heap is probably corrupt before you even enter addToDatabase. Are you mixing versions of Visual Studio or using a Release dll in a debug application. Remember it is generally not safe to use a dll compiled with a different version of Visual Studio in your application. This creates more than 1 independent heap.

Comment: @drescherjm, addToDatabase is my own implementation, and though on Windows 7 but I'm using MinGW.

Comment: @Flexo, did the editing for minimal and complete.

Comment: I think you should use `#include <iostream> ` and clear buffers in the beginning

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Duplicate question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786994/c-getline-isnt-waiting-for-input-from-console-when-called-multiple-times).

basically, `cin>>` doesn't remove new lines from the buffer when the user presses enter. `getline()` mistakes this for user input along with enter.

You can use `cin.ignore()` to get rid of those extra characters before using `getline()`.

Answer (score 0):

There are newline characters in cin's buffer, so getline() takes it as an input from user.

You should [flush cin buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257091/how-do-i-flush-the-cin-buffer) before using getline().