# Accepting input in relation to an array of structures

Tags: c++

I am currently practicing C++ and I am doing this question from the textbook C++ Primer Plus, and I am stuck at this very last step. Basically I am to make an array out of a structure that contains info a car and **the issue that I am having trouble with is recording the user's input.**

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct car{
    std::string make;
    int year;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalog? ";
    int lim;
    std::cin >> lim;
    car* info = new car[lim];
    for(int i = 0; i<lim; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the make: ";
        getline(std::cin, info[i].make); // problem here..
        std::cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
        std::cin >> info[i].year; // problem here as well :(
    }
    std::cout << "here is your collection:\n";
    while(int i = 0 < lim)
    {
        std::cout << info[i].make << " " << info[i].year << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "here is your collection:\n"
        i++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help explain why it isn't working?

Specifically, my issue is that it is not getting my input correctly, and my exe file seems to skip the input of the "make" question and jumps to the year..Then it crashes into oblivious..possibly a segmentation fault.

Comment: Your question is underspecified. What is the problem and what are you having trouble with? I highly suspect your issue is: [c++ getline() isn't waiting for input from console when called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7786994/c-getline-isnt-waiting-for-input-from-console-when-called-multiple-times)

Comment: `while(int i = 0 < lim)` Whatever you think this does, it doesn't do that. I think, but am not sure, it makes `i == 1` every time through the loop, and results in infinite loop. You have already written one loop iterating over all array elements - why do you feel the need to invent a new syntax?

Comment: Is your problem recording user input or does it have to do with the output? Because as Igor pointed out, your while loop won't output what you're expecting.

Comment: @Harrison The infinite loop is likely what is causing the program to "crash" (the program has stopped working is what I'm guessing the OP is experiencing.) The input issue is a duplicate.

Comment: Guys, thanks for input, I managed to fix the underlying issue, I ended up adding a cin.get() after the initial call for cin to read the \n still left in the input line, and then another cin.get() after getting the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you read numbers using

```
std::cin >> lim;
```

and

```
    std::cin >> info[i].year;
```

a newline character is left on the stream, which is picked up by `getline` as valid input.

You need to add code to ignore the rest of the line.

```
std::cin >> lim;
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

and

```
    std::cin >> info[i].year;
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')
```

See documentation on [`istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Also, change

```
while(int i = 0 < lim)
{
    std::cout << info[i].make << " " << info[i].year << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "here is your collection:\n"
    i++;
}
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
{
    std::cout << info[i].make << " " << info[i].year << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "here is your collection:\n"
}
```

Comment: I managed to fix my while loop, but your fix for the first part seems a bit advanced, I haven't gotten far into c++ yet. Is there perhaps a more understandable noob method?

Comment: @TakShing, `istream::ignore` can be used to ignore data on the input stream up to the given number of characters. You can replace `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` by a simple number, such as `100` and it should work too.

Comment: Okay, thanks and I also fixed it just now by adding a cin.get() to get the newline lol.

Comment: @TakShing, remember that if you happen to enter the space bar after the numbers, you will run into the same problem. `std::ignore` is a more robust way to eat up the rest of the line.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct car{
    std::string make;
    int year = 0;
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0; //increment value

    std::cout << "How many cars do you wish to catalog? ";
    int lim;
    std::cin >> lim;
    car* info = new car[lim];
    for(i;  i < lim; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the make: ";
        std::cin >> info[i].make; // change to cin, just like the one for year
        std::cout << "Please enter the year made: ";
        std::cin >> info[i].year; // this was fine
    }
    std::cout << "here is your collection:\n";
    i = 0; //resets the increment value
    while(i < lim)
    {
        std::cout << info[i].make << " " << info[i].year << std::endl;
        //std::cout << "here is your collection:\n"
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I avoided using cin because what if the input had spaces as well such as Super Mazda? cin will only read up to Super, so I decided to use getline because it reads the entire thing.

Comment: Anyways, I fixed it by adding cin.get() and I gave you a +1 up for your help!

Answer (score 0):

combining cin and getline is ... funky. cin never read the newline character from the first string, so your first getline call is going to pretty much just return a blank string. What I normally do when I have an issue like this is perform a throwaway getline() call after my cin.

combining getline and cin is not normally very friendly. Maybe you should switch to all getlines and do a little bit of string manipulation?

Comment: So I should getline my lim and the info.year?