# How to read std::string after reading int?

Tags: c++

My goal is to read a string input after reading an int input. The problem is I'm either getting an error or getline() isn't waiting for input from console.

#### I tried the following

Original method:

```
int num;
string name;
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> num;
cout << "Enter name: ";
cin >> name;
```

However if I enter name which has multiple words, the prompt won't take any more inputs.

Second method:

I tried this

```
int num;
string name;
cout << "Enter number: ";
cin >> num;
cout << "Enter name: ";
getline(cin, name);
```

But according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7787253/5767939), this method is wrong.

Method 3:

Finally I tried this

```
int num;
string name;
cout << "Enter number: ";
//cin >> num;
getline(cin, num);
cout << "Enter name: ";
getline(cin, name);
```

But it gives me error `error: no matching function for call to 'getline'`

Comment: Use [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) to read and discard the newline from the numeric input. Calling [`getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) with wrong arguments won't help you.

Comment: `std::getline` takes a `string&` as its second parameter, so `std::getline(cin, num)` can't find a matching definition.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22660390/5767939) answer helped! Thanks